# Bad performance transfer file with samba

Tags: samba

I have made a torrent client/file server with raspberry pi 2, using a 16 GB SD card class 10 for raspbian and a 16 GB USB to store files that i transferred with samba. Pi is connected with LAN cable with the speed of  680 KB/sec.

During the transfer, the smbd daemon is using 1-2% of CPU and has up to 500 MB of RAM free, any ideas?

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest Samba 2 - There are massive performance fixes in there.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output of ifconfig to see what the Ethernet is connecting at, also run drive performance tests to see what your read write speed on your USB drive is.

Comment: Test result is: `655360000 bytes (655 MB) copied, 81.2599 s, 8.1 MB/s`, seems ok

Comment: And ifconfig? I wonder if you're connecting slow. Also, check ping/tracert times to the other machines. 

Do you have any other machines on the network you can test with?

Answer (score 0):

I solved, the problem is the powerline adapter. With a direct cable it's work perfectly (8-10 MB/sec). Thanks for your patience and sorry